# How can I prevent form from submitting to server when integrating Stripe with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, forms, stripe-payments

I have been following Stripe's tutorial for creating my own form with their API. Long story short, what happens is, when the form is submitted, a bit of Javascript sends the data to their servers and then appends the `stripeToken` input field. The form is then submitted again, and my Flask app is supposed to read the value of this new form field. However, when I try running my code, it yields a 500 Internal Server Error, which I assume is because Flask is immediately looking for the form `stripeToken`, which does not exist when it first checks. Is there Javascript or Python I can add to not call `request.form['stripeToken']` until after Stripe has added it?

Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Settings</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v1/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('STRIPE_TEST_KEY');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="payments">
        <h1>Add a credit card</h1>
        <form action="{{ url_for('stats') }}" method="POST" id="payment-form">
```

And here is the Python:

```
@app.route('/stats', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stats():
#if signed in as user       
if session['signed-in-accttype'] == 'u':
    u=User.query.get(session['signed-in-id'])
    if request.method == 'POST': 
            stripe.api_key = "STRIPE_TEST_KEY"
            token = request.form['stripeToken']

        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            card=token,
            description=u.uemail
            )
        #update stripe id
        u.ustripe_id = customer.id
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('stats'))       
    return render_template('settings.html', u=u)
```

And the logs:

```
2013-04-23T01:57:39.590458+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.44.13.218 - - [2013-04-23 01:57:39] "GET /stats HTTP/1.1" 200 2348 0.014429
2013-04-23T01:57:39.590171+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/stats host=ancient-oasis-5770.herokuapp.com fwd="99.110.189.136" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=2230
2013-04-23T01:57:39.804162+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-oasis-5770.herokuapp.com fwd="99.110.189.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=238
2013-04-23T01:57:39.808201+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.127.113.186 - - [2013-04-23 01:57:39] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 347 0.000610
2013-04-23T01:57:54.934252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/stats host=ancient-oasis-5770.herokuapp.com fwd="99.110.189.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=500 bytes=291
2013-04-23T01:57:54.931497+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.92.74.166 - - [2013-04-23 01:57:54] "POST /stats HTTP/1.1" 500 412 0.020936
2013-04-23T01:57:55.133776+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.44.58.92 - - [2013-04-23 01:57:55] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 347 0.000603
2013-04-23T01:57:55.137417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-oasis-5770.herokuapp.com fwd="99.110.189.136" dyno=web.1 connect=24ms service=43ms status=404 bytes=238
2013-04-23T01:57:58.710721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/stats host=ancient-oasis-5770.herokuapp.com fwd="99.110.189.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=2230
2013-04-23T01:57:58.714328+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.44.45.210 - - [2013-04-23 01:57:58] "GET /stats HTTP/1.1" 200 2348 0.012623
2013-04-23T01:57:58.826291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-oasis-5770.herokuapp.com fwd="99.110.189.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=238
2013-04-23T01:57:58.827469+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.44.13.218 - - [2013-04-23 01:57:58] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 347 0.000772
```

UPDATE: here is the traceback running it locally)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/Zach/Desktop/t/t.py", line 20, in stats
    stripe.api_key = "STRIPE_TEST_KEY"
NameError: global name 'stripe' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2013 22:11:03] "GET /stats?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2013 22:11:03] "GET /stats?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2013 22:11:03] "GET /stats?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2013 22:11:03] "GET /stats?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2013 22:11:03] "GET /stats?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=source.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2013 22:11:03] "GET /stats?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

UPDATE 2: I deduced that the above error on my local, testing script was because I forgot to `import stripe`. Doing so made it run fine. However, this same code continues to produce the 500 error when run on Heroku.

UPDATE 3 (revelation): So my Stripe dashboard says that I am, indeed, creating new users. Thus, I think it is fair to assume that all of the code up until (and including) `customer = stripe.Customer.create` works. So could the 500 error be caused by my modifying my database?

Comment: Have you actually checked the log from your Flask server to see what Python error that 500 ISE is actually coming from? Just randomly guessing what the cause is may lead you astray. If you *have* checked the log, please copy-paste the error here.

Comment: @Amber yes I have – sorry I neglected to post it. I have updated my question.

Comment: I don't see an error message listed there, only a 500 response code.

Comment: @Amber I ran it locally (so the line numbers are different), but I have updated my question with the traceback

Answer (score 0):

NameError: global name 'stripe' is not defined

Looks like you forgot to import `stripe`.

Comment: Sorry for the plethora of updates, but that was a typo when I copied the script to run it locally. I just checked my Stripe dashboard, and it says that I am successfully creating users with each form submit (though I am still seeing the 500 error). That being the case, I think it is fair to assume that the problem must stem from the code after I call ``customer = stripe.Customer.create``

Answer (score 0):

After checking my Stripe dashboard, I realized that customers were being created properly. So the error lied in the following code, where I update the stripe_id for the user in my database. 
The problem was the Flask column for the stripe id was expecting an integer. However, Stripe assigns id's as a string.